# Fraction or integer parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, rational-numbers

#### Question

How can the following implementation of `fractionParse` be made
less ugly? (Preserving unreduced numerators and denominators is supposed to be a *feature*---as shown in the second example---so using `readMaybe s :: Maybe (Ratio Int)` doesn't really help.)

Things that irked me in the process of writing it, include:

- Not being able to find a way to use do-notation in conjunction with `Maybe` in a way that would return as soon as `Just` appears rather than when the first `Nothing` appears. In other words a `Maybe` monad instance that emulates `or` rather than `and`.
- `case` and pattern matching colliding in unhelpful ways, forcing me to write nested `if-then-else`s.

#### Usage examples

```
λ> fractionParse "2/3"
Fraction 2 3
λ> fractionParse "12 / 6"
Fraction 12 6
λ> fractionParse "23"
Whole 23
λ> fractionParse "a"
Rubbish
λ> fractionParse "2/3/4"
Rubbish
λ> fractionParse "2%3"
Rubbish
```

#### Implementation

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.String.Utils (split)
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)

data FractionParse = Fraction Int Int
                   | Whole Int
                   | Rubbish deriving (Show, Eq)

fractionParse :: String -> FractionParse
fractionParse s = let i = maybeInt s
                      r = maybeNumDenom s in
  if isJust r
  then let (Just (n,d)) = r in Fraction n d
  else if isJust i
       then Whole (fromJust i)
       else Rubbish

maybeInt :: String -> Maybe Int
maybeInt s = readMaybe s

maybeNumDenom :: String -> Maybe (Int, Int)
maybeNumDenom s = do
  if containsExactlyOneSlash s then Just () else Nothing
  let [ns,ds] = split "/" s
  n <- readMaybe ns
  d <- readMaybe ds
  return (n,d)

containsExactlyOneSlash s = (length $ filter (=='/') s) == 1
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`First` `Monoid` instance for `Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First). Used like—

```
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (First(..))

fractionParse :: String -> FractionParse
fractionParse s = fromMaybe Rubbish . getFirst
                $ foldMap First [ maybeFraction s
                                , maybeWhole s
                                ]
```

It doesn't make sense to encode your own failure values in your datatypes, so I'd remove the `Rubbish` Constructor.

```
data FractionParse = Fraction Int Int | Whole Int
  deriving (Show, Eq)

fractionParse :: String -> Maybe FractionParse
```

Use [`Control.Monad.guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) instead of manually sending up your own sentinel values (as in `maybeNumDenom`).

```
maybeNumDenom s = do
  guard $ containsExactlyOneSlash s
  -- ...
```

Take advantage of [incremental parsing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads) to implement `maybeNumDenom`, then you won't have to do so much extraneous filtering, counting, and finger crossing. And by removing the `Rubbish` constructor, at the point you have a correct parse you know you can return a `Fraction`, so—

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

maybeFraction :: String -> Maybe FractionParse
maybeFraction s = listToMaybe $ do
  (n, '/':s') <- reads s
  (d, "") <- reads s'
  return (Fraction n d)
```

The above function operates in the list monad. `listToMaybe` converts a list to a `Maybe` value by returning `Just` the first element of the list, or `Nothing` in the case of an empty list. `reads :: Read a => String -> [(a, String)]` produces possible parses from a given string, returning the remainder of the unparsed string as the second element of each tuple. Binding to `(d, "")` ensures that only parses that consume the whole string will be returned.

Comment: Lots of good stuff there, thanks! The original `fractionParse` was a lot more tolerant WRT whitespace than `maybeFraction`. For now I'm struggling to recover that tolerance.

Comment: @jacg Oops! Fixed.

Comment: It could probably do with `import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)` too, for those who want to copy 'n' paste.

Comment: The Alternative instance of Maybe also has First behavior. `fractionParse s = fromMaybe Rubbish $ maybeFraction s <|> maybeWhole s`